Some tag suggestions don't show up when entering their initial characters in the tag field
Some tag suggestions don't show up when entering their initial letters in the tags field when editing the tags field.
For example, on Arqade, the following is shown:

..even though the tag Android exists:

Tested on Chrome on Android 13 (Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra).
Maybe it's because one can't create "and" as a tag.

I think it's because of the and because the only other things I tested that don't work are stuff like "or".

@Joachim thanks, you're looking at a different place in the user interface.

Reproduced with and, or, and not.

No repro in tags page, please clarify where exactly this happens.

@ShadowWizard When asking a question. The screenshot is from Arqade, where 'android' is a valid tag, yet it doesn't show up (actually, nothing shows up) when entering 'and' in the tags list (reproducible).

@Joachim ah, but also when editing a post. Thanks.

It's painful.
